# Bootstrap navbar collapse working properly in desktop but not in smaller devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap navbar-default is working properly and great in desktop. But when i am using chrome's dev tools to check in in mobile devive is not working, is really messy like not background.

This is my html and my css from my navbar.

Html code

```
  <div data-affix="" data-fix-at-screen="top" data-clip-at-control="top" data-enable-lg="" data-enable-md="" data-enable-sm="" class="bd-affix-1 navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
 <div class="container">

<div class="navbar-header">
  <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".btnCollapse">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Drop<span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li>
              <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                      <ul class="col-sm-3">
                            <li><a href="#"#">Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#">Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#">Link 1</a>
                            </li>                              
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="col-sm-3">
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>                              
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="col-sm-3">
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>                              
                      </ul>
                      <ul class="col-sm-3">
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#"#"> Link 1</a>
                            </li>                              
                      </ul>
                  </div>
              </div>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Desti</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Deals</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

 </div>
 <!-- end container -->
</div>
```

CSS code

```
        th {
          color:#D5DDE5;;
          background:#1b1e24;
          font-weight: 100;
          text-align: center;
        }

        tr {
          color:#666B85;
          font-size:16px;
          font-weight:normal;
          text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(256, 256, 256, 0.1);
        }

        td {
          padding:20px;
          text-align:center;
          vertical-align:middle;
          font-weight:600;
          font-size:12px;
          text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        }
        #menu-container {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            width: 150px;
        }

        .nav > li.dropdown.open {
          position: static;
        }

        .nav > li.dropdown.open .dropdown-menu {
          display: table;
          border-radius: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          text-align: center;
          left: 0;
          right: 0;
        }

        .dropdown-menu > li {
          display: table-cell;
          height: 50px;
          line-height: 50px;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
          .dropdown-menu > li {
            display: block;
          }
        }
        .navbar-default{
            background-color: #933e6e;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            margin: 0;
            height: 60px;
        }
        .navbar-nav{
            width: 100%;
            color: #000;
        }

        .nav > li {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            width: 12.5%;
        }
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
            color: #000;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            border-radius: 0px;
            display: block;
            white-space: nowrap;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
            color: #dddddd;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            font-weight: normal;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin-right: 10px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            border-radius: 0px;
            display: block;
            white-space: nowrap;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .affix{
            width: 100%;
            right: 0%;
            left: auto;
            top: 0px;
            bottom: auto;
            position: fixed;
        }
        .nav .navbar-li{
          margin-right: 20%;
        }

        .container .row li{
            list-style-type: none;
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 16px;
        }
        .container .row a:hover{
            color: #333;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

JS code

```
$('#menu-container li').hover(function() {
    //show its submenu
    $('ul', this).fadeIn(100);

}, function() {
    //hide its submenu
    $('div ul', this).fadeOut(100);
});
```

Already tried to place a background but i have a search box beneath and was stupid idea. Thats how it looks right now when i click the menu

[image]

Any suggestions?

http://jsfiddle.net/DopeAt/r4vL6v1e/

Comment: You are removing and replacing some of bootstrap classes that are applied to default items and that's why you are getting that behavior (if you remove your CSS customization's you will see that everything works as expected.) if you want to modify colors and customizations you should use themes instead of particular itmes. If you just want to modify an item then create a new class and use that one for your item. Trying to modify boostrap's default classes is a recipe for issues :) unless you know EXACTLY what you are doing.

Comment: Yes you right mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProgrammerV5 help me see that the class navbar should not be there. So i change it to that and is working

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse btnCollapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<div class="btnCollapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
```